# Should I do another Master's in CS to take courses covering recent developments in my field relevant to my work?

Tags: computer-science, second-degree

I already have a C.S. Master's degree with computer vision experience, but this was before deep learning. It's been 4 years since I've been out of school and most companies want engineers with deep learning experience.

I'm thinking about keeping my current job and doing another Master's degree part time because there are courses that I want to take. What do you guys think of having two Master's in computer science?

Comment: I don't think you need two Master's degrees.

Comment: Does your company intend to sponsor your degree?

Comment: A graduate degree should train you how to learn about new areas, especially if they are related. Do you feel ill-equipped to read on your own and do projects? There are also great Coursera classes out there on deep learning.

Comment: @GoodDeeds nope, but I won't have to quit my job so there is income.

Comment: @kjacks21 It like there are particular courses that I want to take in the program. And, if I were to do it on my own, I think there could be progress, but not sure if it will be result it anything tangible like a paper/patent/certificate.

Answer (score 4):

You finally want to convince a potential employer that you know enough about hot topic ABC (in your current case "deep learning") to get the job. Best thing is personal hands-on industryt experience with the topic. If I were this potential employer, I'd as well consider someone who made significant contributions in a relevant open-source project.

As the hot topics in software change quite frequently over time (I've been in the industry for 30+ years and seen an awful lot of different hypes), you can't continue to add more and more Master's degrees - or do you want to still attend university MS programs when being 50+ years old, and finally retire with a collection of maybe ten different computer science MS degrees?

My recommendation:

- You got an MS in computer science already, and that shows your basic competence. No need to repeat that with a slightly different specialization.
- Acquire the necessary knowledge on the interesting hot topic ABC, maybe by attending a course, or by reading online materials or whatever you prefer. (And continue to do so with topics of interest all over your career.)
- Depending on the country / culture where you seek a job, get a certificate documenting your knowledge.
- Find a project where you can apply that knowledge, either in your current job, or volunteering in an open-source project.
- Be quick. Don't waste years of time studying before you apply for a job. By the time you're ready, there will be a different hot topic, and topic-ABC specialists aren't relevant any more. As long as the topic is really hot, there won't be enough experienced specialists available, so the industry will also accept a lot of training-on-the-job candidates.